# Visualize tree from *.dot file

Tags: java, antlr, graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I need to visualize a tree which I have gotten from an ANTLR parser and written to a .dot file by catching console output that the ANLR dot generator produces.

```
    MyDOTTreeGenerator generator = new MyDOTTreeGenerator();
    PrintStream old = System.out;
    try {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(graphFile)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(generator.toDOT(root));
    System.out.flush();
    System.setOut(old);
```

Question is:
1. Is there a way to visualize the .dot file in my program, Swing component for example.
2. I have read/tried to visualize with the help of Grappa library + Graphviz toolkit using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217288/grappa-graphviz-dot-visualization-problem-and-questions) => is there a way I can pack the Graphviz toolkit in my program, so that I can visualize the graph **without the end user having to download and/or install something.**

Answer (score 0):

1. I would start by googling something like dot files java, actually there seem to be multiple solutions, like [ZGRViewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html)
2. It is possible to start external programs from Java, and there are many ways to create installers that install additional programs.

Comment: 1. I have googled well enough. ZGRViewer is just an improved visualizer based on Graphviz having no option whatsoever to embed in Java applications.
2. I don't want to unnecessarily overcomplicate the program by downloading/installing to just view a simple tree graph and want to keep such actions at program level. Edited the question.